# Debugging a Django backend inside a Docker Container with VSCode, using a docker volume

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I have a Docker container running a Django Back-End server in the URL: `127.0.0.1:7080`, this is, the port where the container is running is `7080` and the Django local project was linked with the project inside the Docker container using a docker volume.

My question is: Is there a method to debug the local project with the python congfiguration inside the Docker container? I think that maybe I should configure the `launch.json` file.

I hope someone could resolve me this issue.

There's some configuration code inside the `launch.json` file.

```
{
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app/"
                }
            ],
            "port": 7080,
            "host": "127.0.0.1"
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the ["Remote - Containers" extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) so you can develop within the container itself. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers has detailed instructions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I didn't get notifications about the removals and I was catching up on unanswered questions after vacation, so I'm not sure which other ones you removed.
As for flagging comments of moderators, your initial comment came off a rather brusque and short with me, hence the flag. I do appreciate the edit you made.

Comment: Well, I deleted this one and another duplicate/very similar one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57998740/6451573. I'm cleaning up other comments now.